# Groovy how to find a value from an ArrayList in a Map

Tags: list, arraylist, groovy, hashmap, findall

I have an ArrayList and a list of Maps.

```
 def paint= ["blue", "green", "red"]
 def cars = [[color:"black", year:2018, id: 1345], [color:"blue", year:2009, id: 1241], [color:"green", year:2009, id: 1525], [color:"yellow", year:2009, id: 1891]]
```

I want to search the List Map and find id's of the cars with the colors mentioned in the paint ArrayList and return an ArrayList like shown below

```
result  [1241, 1525]
```

I have the below mentioned code however it only shows the result with the first mentioned color in the ArrayList.

```
def result = cars.findAll{it.color in paint}
def resultID = result.id.join(",")
```

This returns only

```
resultID  [1241]
```

Comment: This works fine for me once the syntax errors are fixed.

Comment: yeah this works fine for me too `1241,1525`

Comment: Thank you @DaveNewton and @Deadpool I just tried `prinln cars.getClass` and `println paint.getClass` both of them are `class java.util.ArrayList`. I am getting cars from an API call hence the confusion,  I guess my question has changed how would i accomplish my desired result of getting both id's between 2 ArrayList

Comment: How you're doing it now is one way to do it. There's no way to know what your *actual* problem is because the code as shown works.

Comment: Update: I fixed the issue. This code as stated above by everyone works fine. The issue was that in the Jenkins job parameter i was separating each element with  ", " instead of "," that extra space after the comma was the culprit. Thank you everyone!